# Dataproc Reading from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to read a csv or txt file from GCS in a Dataproc pyspark Application. I have tried so many things. So far the most promising:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import os
import sys
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "/usr/lib/spark/"
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/spark/python/")

sc =SparkContext()
sql_sc = SQLContext(sc)
```

eithe:

```
pandas_df = pd.read_csv('{BUCKET}/user2user_relations.csv')
s_df = sql_sc.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
```

or

```
data = sc.textFile('gs://{BUCKET}/user2user_relations.csv')
```

There is no need for the pandas workaround. I want to end up with an RDD for spark ALS Recommendation.
The error I am getting is:

```
Job [fdcad5bcf77343e2b8782097cd7450cb] submitted.
Waiting for job output...
18/08/08 16:50:20 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @2662ms
18/08/08 16:50:20 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server: jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
18/08/08 16:50:20 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server: Started @2751ms
18/08/08 16:50:20 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@41335d47{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
18/08/08 16:50:21 INFO com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS version: 1.6.7-hadoop2
18/08/08 16:50:21 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at new-try-gcs-pd-m/10.164.0.2:8032
18/08/08 16:50:24 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1533726146765_0018
dataproc-d3d8d55c-05b3-4211-adf2-2014ebdbc20c-europe-west4
go-de-internal
gs://dataproc-d3d8d55c-05b3-4211-adf2-2014ebdbc20c-europe-west4/
gs://dataproc-d3d8d55c-05b3-4211-adf2-2014ebdbc20c-europe-west4/user2user_relations.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/fdcad5bcf77343e2b8782097cd7450cb/pyspark_gcs_acess.py", line 19, in <module>
    pandas_df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 452, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 234, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 542, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 679, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1041, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "parser.pyx", line 332, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:3218)
  File "parser.pyx", line 559, in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas/parser.c:5594)
IOError: File gs://{}/user2user_relations.csv does not exist
18/08/08 16:50:28 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@41335d47{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.pyspark) Job [fdcad5bcf77343e2b8782097cd7450cb] entered state [ERROR] while waiting for [DONE].
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you list your file with gsutil, e.g. `gsutil ls gs://<bucket_name>/user2user_relations.csv`?

Comment: yes :) the file exists. I checked that already and also tried to call another file in the dataproc job. same thing

Comment: Do you have any special network configuration? VPC for example? And just to be sure, did you try to list file with gsutil after sshing in Dataproc VM?

Comment: "Do you have any special network configuration? VPC for example?" - no | "And just to be sure, did you try to list file with gsutil after sshing in Dataproc VM?" - yes, the file is there

Comment: @JohannaSchacht Asking a clarification question: Is is right to assume that `BUCKET` is a place holder and you are replacing this in your code? asking this because the error log seems to show that the `BUCKET` is not replaces i.e  `gs://{}/user2user_relations.csv does not exist` is not a valid GCS bucket location

Comment: How big is your source file? I.e. do you need to access it DIRECTLY from GCS or is it acceptable to have it copied onto the Master machine? What you are doing in terms of 'GS://' notation seems right (at least it works for me). But one thing you might want to try is to also 'pass' that file as a parameter with the job submission. That should work as well, but wont' be ideal if the file is very large. For this try --files gs://{BUCKET}/file.csv notation in the Dataproc job command script

Comment: yes! it is a real Bucket and {} is a placeholder, thanks

Comment: copying it to the mastermaching is fine. It is not super big. I am happy with a workaround, but also generally intersted in the "real" solution. Will try passing as a parameter and report back. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pandas will not read directly from GCS using the URI you provided.
Differently from Spark in Dataproc, which has the GCS Connector installed by default.

I suggest if you want to read the same blob from pandas to either:

- Use the GCS python lib to read the blob https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/
  The code may look like:

```py
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
# https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/[bucket-id]/
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-id-here')
# Then do other things...
blob = bucket.get_blob('remote/path/to/file.txt')

df = pd.read_csv(blob.download_as_string())
```

- Or, copy the file to the local directory first, using the command `gsutil cp gs://bucket/blob /local/folder/blob`

```py
df = pd.read_csv('/local/folder/blob')
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the BUCKET value, just replace {BUCKET} with your bucket name or set the variable

```
data = sc.textFile('gs://{BUCKET}/user2user_relations.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the next error

```
gs://{}/user2user_relations.csv does not exist
```

It looks like you are missing your BUCKET name. This can be fixed by just adding the name of the BUCKET in the brackets {} that you are trying to use; take the code below as an example:

```
--files gs://{my_bucket}/file.csv
```